# How can I format currency with no decimals but only when the decimal is zero?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I am currently using the following to format a decimal as a currency.

```
double value = 12345.6789;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));

// Result: $12,345.68
```

Which is the behaviour I want, except when the decimals are 0, as in `double value = 12345.00;`

Then the result should be `$12,345`

I've tried variations using `#` like `.ToString("C.##"` etc. but I can't get it to work as I'd like.

Comment: off-topic, but don't use `double` to hold monetary values.

Comment: @Mathew neglects to mention why `double` is inappropriate for monetary values - that it is an approximate numerical representation of decimals which will prevent equality comparisons from functioning properly, amongst numerous other issues.

Comment: @Matthew, I don't, this is a string formatting example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#CFormatString

Comment: Is it possible to just do a string replace at the end?  Something like `"0.00".Replace(".00", "");`, I haven't seen a format that does currency the way you want.

Comment: @Matthew absolutely possible I just wonder if that is the most efficient way :S

Answer (score 4):

Using `decimal`, you could determine which format string to use:

```
//decimal value = 12345.6789m;
decimal value = 12345.0000m;

var formatString = Decimal.Truncate(value) == value ? "C0" : "C";

Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(formatString, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this `.ToString("0.##")`

Comment: how about this `string result = (numba % 1 == 0 ? numba.ToString("C0") : numba.ToString("C2"))`

Comment: Your first .ToString("0.##") method would produce "3.9" for $3.90, which isn't exactly typical currency notation.